# file operations and optimize the python code

Tags: python

I am writing a code which should return True only when a file contains a non-zero integer and False in all other cases.

```
import os
def start():
    if os.path.exists('hi.txt'):
        f = open('hi.txt', 'r')
        size = os.path.getsize('hi.txt')
        if size > 0:
            s = f.read()
            if int(s) > 0:
                return  True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False

st = start()
print("status", st)
```

I am getting the expected result but want to shorten and optimize it. How can I optimize the code.

Comment: If the code is complete and works, it should be on Code Review instead. This site is primarily for fixing broken code. Note though, they'd want a example of its use, along with example data.

Comment: One thing you could do would be to get rid of all those else clauses and just have one return False at the end of the function. If the interpreter hits that line you know you never entered a sufficient number of if blocks to return True...

Comment: Your code works for text files which contain a single integer but fails for text files which contain anything else (e.g. 2 integers, a floating point literal, the string "Hello World", etc.), so I don't think it could be described as fully working. Your testing has ignored various edge cases.

Comment: Another point is "why avoid the `if os.exists: open` paradigm?" You are potentially introducing the case (called a race condition) where the file might be deleted/moved/etc during the switch from the `if` to the `open` statement. In general, it is much better to try to just open the file, and handle the potential exception accordingly, as with chepner's answer. This produces behavior that is much easier to predict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of your code is simply there to avoid an exception being raised. But when an exception *would* be raised, you return `False`. So just let the exception be raised and catch it.

```
def start():
    try:
        with open("hi.txt") as f:
            s = f.read()
            return int(s) > 0
    except Exception:
        return False
```